# TeamCity VCS build trigger by regex works strange

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, branching-and-merging, build-triggers

I use TeamCity 10 for continuous integration and there is a problem with build trigger configuring. I need to add build to build queue by matching special word in VSC commit comment, so I make VCS trigger with regular expression:

```
+:comment=#testbuild:**
```

But now I have strange situation:

- if I commit to my branch with comment including special word, build adds to queue. It's OK.
- if I commit to my branch without special word in comment, build doesn't add to queue. It's OK.
- but if I merge other branch with my branch(it contains changesets with special word in comment), other branch build adds to queue too, though its comment doesn't contain special word. NOT OK!

Why does it happen and how can I fix it? Any idea?

Thanks.